# How to correctly free memory when using CString with cgo in golang?

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I'm trying to understand how to correctly free memory when using CString with `cgo` in `golang`

This is the **working** code that I want **to make** "**memory-safe**":

`basic.go` :

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import (
        "github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go"
)

var lan lingua.Language


//export Langdetectfunct
func Langdetectfunct(text *C.char) int {


    textS := C.GoString(text);

    detector := lingua.NewLanguageDetectorBuilder().
        FromAllLanguages().
        Build()

    language, _ := detector.DetectLanguageOf(textS)

    return int(language)

}

func main() {}
```

`basic1.cpp` :

```
#include "basic.h"

int main() {
    auto text = "It is a beautiful day, today";
    int res = Langdetectfunct(const_cast<char *>(text));
    std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
}
```

After building basic.go with `c-shared` buildmode:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c-shared basic.go
```

and compiling basic1.cpp with `basic.so` :

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ g++ -o basic basic1.cpp ./basic.so
```

I get the correct output:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ ./basic 
res: 17
```

And that's fine...

But: how to make the code "memory-safe"?

I tried in this way:

`basic.go` :

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

import (
        "github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go"
)

var lan lingua.Language

//export Langdetectfunct
func Langdetectfunct(text *C.char) int {

    textS := C.GoString(text);

    detector := lingua.NewLanguageDetectorBuilder().
        FromAllLanguages().
        Build()

    language, _ := detector.DetectLanguageOf(textS)

    return int(language)

    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))
}

func main() {}
```

But, when, building, I get, understandably, this error:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c-shared basic.go
./basic.go:39:1: missing return
```

If I put `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))` before the return statement:

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

import (
        "github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go"
)

var lan lingua.Language

//export Langdetectfunct
func Langdetectfunct(text *C.char) int {

    textS := C.GoString(text);

    detector := lingua.NewLanguageDetectorBuilder().
        FromAllLanguages().
        Build()

    language, _ := detector.DetectLanguageOf(textS)

    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))

    return int(language)

}

func main() {}
```

I get : `free(): invalid pointer` error, when running the executable:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c-shared basic.go
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ g++ -o basic basic1.cpp ./basic.so
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ ./basic 
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Where you expect the malloc was called to allocate text? If it was not then trying to C.free it does not make sense.